# Program to pipe output of one process to other process using execv

Tags: c

I am trying to execute "sudo conntrack -E -p udp -e NEW" command and then pipe the output of this command to "logger" command, but this doesnt work. anything obvious that is going wrong?
so parent is the "sudo conntrack...." which forks the child "logger ..."

```
void main () {

pid_t  pid;
int    status;
int j=0;
int exe_process;
FILE *prt1;
FILE *prt2;
int fd[2];

char *arg[]={ "sudo", "/usr/sbin/conntrack", "-E", "-p", "udp", "-e", "NEW", NULL };
char *arg1[]={ "/usr/bin/logger", "-t", "log-conntrack", "-p", "daemon.notice", NULL };


if (pipe(fd) < 0)
 printf("pipe error\n");

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)       /* fork a child process           */
    {
            printf("ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)           /* for the parent process:         */
    {
            printf("In parent process %d\n",getpid());
            close(fd[0]);

            if (execvp("/usr/sbin/conntrack", arg)  < 0)       /* execute the command  */
            {
                    printf("ERROR: exec failed\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
           prt1=fdopen(fd[1], "ab");
    }
    else                                       /* for the child:      */
    {
            printf("In parent child %d\n",getpid());
            close(fd[1]);
            prt2=fdopen(fd[0], "rb");

            if (execvp("/usr/bin/logger", arg1)  < 0)       /* execute the command  */
            {
                    printf("ERROR: exec failed\n");
                    exit(1);
            }

    }
```

}

Comment: Try `popen()` instead of fork and exec.

Comment: Why not just do this in bash or other shell script?

Comment: this program would be a part of the C daemon, so no bash/shell script.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much correct but the main problem is that you need [dup()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/dup.2.html) instead of what you are trying to do with `fdopen`.  `dup` will redirect stdin/stdout the way you want.

```
else if (pid > 0)           /* for the parent process:         */
{
    printf("In parent process %d\n",getpid());
    close(fd[0]);

    close(1);
    dup(fd[1]);

    if (execvp("/usr/sbin/conntrack", arg)  < 0)       /* execute the command  */
    {
        printf("ERROR: exec failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //prt1=fdopen(fd[1], "ab");
}
```

And in the child:

```
    close(0);
    dup(fd[0]);
```

Comment: I changed fdopen to dup(), didnt work, parent execvp is failing, i guess because it is a sudo command, thats why it forks another process?

Comment: Also another question, doing this will run the conntrack and the logger in background? I dont want these processes to die (other the system signals or user issued signals).

Comment: Change the first parm of the execve  of the sudo command to /usr/bin/sudo (or whatever the full path is on your system).  I had my doubts about sudo in this scenario too but I tested it and it works fine.  It prompts for password, etc., before it forks.  Change your printf of error msgs to perror("execvp"), etc., for better error messages.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by run in the background.  It will return you to your shell to free up your command line but you would need to take further steps to detach from the terminal, turn into a daemon and such.